# how i can make a redirect with flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a redirect from a Flask endpoint with

```py
return redirect('/')
```

And gives me a error

```py
File "f:\Host\FLAKS\main.py", line 40, in response
    return redirect('/logout')
TypeError: redirect() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your endpoint? It might provide some helpful context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to take a look at the Flask [redirect() documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.redirect) and especially the [quickstart section about redirects](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors).

Comment: Thanks @M. de Young